# Bubble exception to usestatuspagecodes middleware after exception filter asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, middleware, exceptionfilterattribute

I have the following setup in startup.

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/mvc/error/", "?statusCode={0}");
```

I also have an ExceptionFilter setup using AddMvcCore(). The exception filter is below.

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        ApiError apiError;
        switch (context.Exception)
        {
            case ApiException exception:
                // handle explicit 'known' API errors
                var ex = exception;
                context.Exception = null;
                apiError = new ApiError(ex.StatusCode, ex.Message) { Messages = ex.Messages };
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex.StatusCode;
                break;

            case UnauthorizedAccessException _:
                apiError = new ApiError(401, "Unauthorized Access");
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                _loggingService.LogError<ApiExceptionFilter>(LogCategory.Api,  context.Exception);
                break;

            default:
                // unhandled errors
                apiError = new ApiError(500, context.Exception.GetBaseException().Message) { Detail = context.Exception.StackTrace };
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                _loggingService.LogError<ApiExceptionFilter>(LogCategory.Api, context.Exception);
                break;
        }

        // always return a JSON result
        context.Result = new JsonResult(apiError);

        base.OnException(context);
    }
```

The problem is when an exception occurs in an action method, the filter kicks in but sends in a JSON result. What I want to do is to bubble the exception up to UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute middleware as well. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the result from the action filter if you want to use the status code middleware as well. Take a look at the pre-conditions of the status code middleware in [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/8dce01f654962580e22e7c96ad4f313574407a40/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesMiddleware.cs#L42-L46), it will skip the status code page pipeline execution if the response body is already set or have been written to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have removed the code where it sets the result. But, I am setting the statuses as shown. During and exception, I am setting 500, Server Error code. But, when caught by the UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute middleware, it is always a 404. Any idea?

Comment: Ok found a fix. Added code to complete current task inside UseExceptionHandler. app.UseExceptionHandler(appbuilder =>
            {
                appbuilder.Run(async (context) => { await Task.CompletedTask; });
            });. This will basically surface the correct context inside the UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute middleware.

Comment: That seems odd. Does just calling `app.UseExceptionHandler()` without params do the trick as well?

Comment: It does not work when app.UseExceptionHandler() is used without parameters. It gives a generic browser error page saying the application is unable to handle the request. Could not figure out why.

Comment: It works for me with a 401 status code, but not with a 403.